# How implement javaFX into an existing game loop

Tags: java, javafx

I have a very simple text-based game where a player moves around a map of room objects. I/O is the terminal.

I want to add a UI to my project via JavaFX but I am unsure the how I should initialize the UI and the game loop together, so my UI elements can observe objects inside my game and update accordingly

My Current code, I have omitted all but the essential code to run the main game loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = GameLauncher.getGameLauncher().launchGameWithThemes();
        game.run();
}
```

A game launcher is used to create a new game object. The run() method is called which enters into a loop, player input is processed and then game objects are manipulated accordingly. Example : ( *move room , pick up item..ect*) The terminal would then print ( *You move to .., you picked up *..)

```
public void run() {

        printStartUpMessage();

        while(true) {

            inputProcessor.processNextCommand(player);

         }
```

If I try to combine this Game Main method with the UI, The JavaFX window becomes unresponsive

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{


        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
        Game game = GameLauncher.getGameLauncher().launchGameWithThemes();
        game.run();

    }
```

Comment: Unless your program is already written with the model separate from the view code, trying to shoehorn linear console code into an event-driven GUI library will be painful at best and disaster at worst. Perhaps best to re-write the code from the ground up, making sure to well separate these concerns.

Comment: There is no easy answer to your question, but at least I can tell you why it's not working. The `while` loop is taking place on the same thread as the code creating the JavaFX window. The thread doing exactly what you tell it to do, running an infinite loop, and it won't do anything else until that loop ends, which it won't because its infinite. I hate to give responses like this but as @HOFE says you're going to have to start over and integrate the game loop into JavaFX. I recommend you look for examples of JavaFX games that are already doing this (there should be plenty).

Comment: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835